# Radius of convergence about a different point

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Let $$\frac1{1+x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-a)^n\ \ a\in\mathbb{R},$$then
what is the radius of convergence of the power series?

I think it should be $\infty$. Is it right?

Comment: I don't understand the equality$$\frac1{1+x^2}=a_n(x-a)^n.$$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I think you want $1+a^2$ instead of $1+ x^2$.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan No. What I meant was $x-a$ instead of $a-a$. I've already edited my comment.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos no, I am just expanding the function $\frac1{1+x^2}$ about an arbitrary point $a\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I thought you substituted $x = a$ (an interesting substitution). Never mind.

Comment: @vidyarthi Then shouldn't there be a $\sum$ sign somewhere?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks. edited the post.

Answer (score 4):

No. The radius of convergence of the series is $\sqrt{1+a^2}$, which turns out to be the distance from $a$ to $\pm i$.

Note that, if $a=0$, then you get the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nx^{2n}$, whose radius of convergence is $1=\sqrt{1+0^2}$.

Comment: What if a=3. Is it still the distance?

Comment: @ElieLouis Sure. If $a=3$, then the answer is $\sqrt{10}$.

Comment: for some reason I was under the impression that if it does not converge in any open interval around $a=3$, then the radius would be $0$. How is the radius defined in this case?

Comment: @ElieLouis The radius of convergence is the only $R\in[0,+\infty]$ such that the Taylor series of $f$ at $a$ converges when $|x-a|<R$ and diverges when $|x-a|>R$.

Comment: oh for some reason I was looking at $|x-a|$ as $|x|$ around $a$, and I was like, "but it diverges at $x=a$ for $a^n$". I mean I looked at the right hand side as $x^n$, not $(x-a)^n$. No clue what happened with me haha. Thanks for the help :).

Answer (score 1):

A good rule to look ratios of convergence is look for "circles of convergence" into the complex plane. Even $\frac1{1+x^2}$ is continuous over R isn't that over the complex plane, and the only converges inside the unitary circle, because the function don't exist for x=+i and x=-i. So, it can't "cross" the unitary circle, for complexes values of x. This fact is translate for the real domain as the intersection of the complex circle of convergence with the real axis. Then, the (real) radius of convergence is |x| < 1, and need to study apart the cases x=1 and x=-1.

Comment: This is true except the series isn't expanded around the origin but at the point $x=a$

Comment: You're right. The question was rewriting, and I don't understand it with the previous statement. The answer then is $|x| < \sqrt{1+a^2}$, which was given by José Carlos, but actually with the same argument: looking for the circle of convergence. And again, must to study apart the extreme values of the interval.

Answer (score 1):

The coefficients can be obtained by the Taylor formula developed around $x=a$. But the computation of the derivatives is uneasy, and it is better to use a change of variable $x^2=t$.

Then

$$\left((1+t)^{-1}\right)^{(n)}=(-1)^nn!(1+t)^{-1-n}$$

and the coefficients of the development around $a^2$ are

$$b_n:=(-1)^n(1+a^2)^{-1-n},$$

$$\frac1{1+t}=\frac1{1+a^2}-\frac t{(1+a^2)^2}+\frac{t^2}{(1+a^2)^3}-\cdots$$

By the ratio test, the radius of convergence for $t$ is

$$1+a^2$$ and the corresponding radius for $x$ is

$$\sqrt{1+a^2}.$$